# Create a function that is one-to-one, but not onto.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question asks us for $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ to create a function that is one-to-one, but not onto. I came up with a solution for this, but the solutions page says that no function exists.

Would $f(x) = x^2$ not be a solution that is one-to-one, but not onto? Or is A both the domain and the range so it is an all or nothing case?

Comment: I believe A is both the domain and the range.

Comment: In general for $f: A\to B$ if $A,B$ are finite non-zero then if $|A|=|B|$ the function is one to one if and only if it's onto, if $|A|>|B|$ the function isn't one-to-one and if $|B|>|A|$ the function isn't onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
x &\in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}\\
f(x) =y &\in {1,2 ,3 , 4 ,5}\\
\end{align}

One-to-one means that each value of $x$ has a different value of $f(x)$

Not onto means that not every value in the set $f(x)$ is used

If it is one-to-one, the minimum size of $f(x)$ is $5$.

However, if it is not onto, then every value of $f(x)$ cannot be used.

This is a contradiction. Do you see why?

Answer (score 2):

$f: A \to A$  and $|A| = n$, then $f$ is one-to-one iff $f$ is onto. This is a well known theorem in an analysis class. You can google a proof on internet.